# Is there a way to skip the "Choose Production" option for a city for a turn?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing a game of Civ V and I captured a city that needed a new production. I sold the city that turn and now the choose production icon is stuck and wont go away even when I press shift-enter. Is there a way to skip the "Choose Production" option for a city for a turn?

Comment: Can you just have the city produce science or gold for 1 turn?

Comment: the problem is that I already sold the city and cannot choose a production for it, sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Have you tried closing Civ V and reopening it?